# Automating this task/code for multiple Gmail accounts? (Selenium/python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The code below I've made using some other sources, im new to python. Anyways the below code runs and works fine. This script will be deployed on a server and run by a scheduler and no human interaction is required. The issue I am having is, there are multiple emails that need this code to run on them. How can I go about doing this? What would be the best solution to do this?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&hl=en&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin") #url


try: #if gb acount more than intended count
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys("email@gmail.com")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='identifierNext']/div/button/div[2]").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("password")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='passwordNext']/div/button/div[2]").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    gmailused =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=':8n']/div/div/div[1]/span[1]").text #xpath for used gb in gmail
    gmailtotal = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=':8n']/div/div/div[1]/span[2]").text #xpath for total gb in gmail
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Used:", gmailused, "Total:", gmailtotal)
    time.sleep(2)
    if float(gmailused.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[0]) >= 0.00:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("GB Count is exceeded")
        driver.get("https://takeout.google.com/")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='i6']/div/div/div[2]/button[2]/span").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("Mail").click()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='i6']/div/div/div[28]/div[2]/div[2]/div/button/span").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("c0").click() 
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@id='yDmH0d']/div[8]/div/div[2]/span/div[4]/button/span").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@id='yDmH0d']/div[8]/div/div[2]/span/div[4]/button[2]/span").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("c15").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@id='yDmH0d']/div[8]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/span/span").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='i6']/div/div[2]/button/span").click()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='i9']/div/div[2]/button/span").click()
        print ("Exported, check email for link")
        time.sleep(4)
        print("Exiting now...")
        driver.quit()
 
    else:
        #if gb count is less, browser close
        print("GB Count is not exceeding")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Exiting now...")
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple solutions to this is creating other functions that get executed once one is done. You could create an array of WebDriver and use each one for a different email, however, a more effective solution to this could be using cookies, where you can bypass the login to each email, and not have to bother logging in or out.
If you have any questions regarding how to do that, let me know.

Comment: Hello. I went and updated my code, so selenium will enter email and password and login to the email, get the quota account and run through the if statement. How would I go about doing the first option? So once the code above runs, how do I run the same code but with different login details, I want to run it about 2-3 times before exiting. Thanks! I was using a google profile that had one of my emails logged in, so it would just load gmail and count it the quota. DOnt think I cant do it for multiple accounts tho.

Comment: I'd recommend you to use arrays, you can have an array storing the username and passwords of the emails, and an array of WebDrivers. Then put that into a loop and just run the program as many times as you want. Make sure that the indexes of the usernames, passwords and WebDrivers match for each use.
I'd love to help more, but I don't know much about coding in python, my main language is java...